# Formula for generating truth table decimals

Tags: javascript, binary, formula, truthtable

Given `n` variables I want to create decimals which equal all the possible binary variations in a truth table. e.g.

For `a`,`b` and `c` let:

```
a = 11110000 (240)
b = 11001100 (204)
c = 10101010 (170)
```

For `p` and `q` let:

```
p - 1100 (12)
q - 1010 (10)
```

I have worked out a formula to create the first number in any set, like so:

```
n = number of variables
x = 2^n

decimal = (2^x) - (2^(x/2));
```

I have implemented this in JavaScript like so:

```
var vars = ["a", "b", "c"];
var bins = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var rows = 1 << vars.length;
    bins[i] = (1 << rows) - (1 << ((rows) / 2));
    console.log(bins[i].toString(2)); // logs 11110000
}
```

I can't work out how to calculate the rest of the numbers, does anyone know a formula to do this?

Comment: if you sweep from 0 to n in decimals, the toString(2) conversions should hit every possible combo along the way.

Comment: @dandavis That doesn't work. 0 - 3 in binary is `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`. Sure I could easily write this alternating 1's and 0's however the computation time grows exponentially and that is not good. I want to find a mathematical formula that means I don't have to create monstrously large loops.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution however it does require a nested loop, this is not ideal as it means the computational time grows exponentially as the `vars` array grows.

I'm starting to think it isn't possible without looping.

Here is my final code. I have no idea how to write it as a mathematical formula so I won't bother.

```
var vars = ["a", "b", "c"];
var bins = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var rows = 1 << vars.length;
    var max = (1 << rows) - 1;
    var diff = (1 << ((rows) / (2 << i))) - 1;
    var output = max - diff;

    var iterations = (1 << i);
    var step = 1 << (vars.length - i);
    for (var j = 1; j < iterations ; j++) {
        output -= (diff << (step * j)); 
    }

    bins[i] = output;

    console.log(bins[i].toString(2));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RbPVx/1/